# Which Factor GUI tutorial/example app?

Tags: user-interface, factor-lang

Is there a non-trivial example application written in Factor language, pregerrably for GUI application which could server as a language tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late, but theres Factor bindings for Qt in the works. They should be in a usable state reasonably soon.

Comment: How soon? Can't find anything in Factor 0.94.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't kept up to date with Factor. I was very very briefly involved in an effort to get Qt working, but then I jumped ship in favour of clojure, so don't know if the Qt support ever matured or if there are still people working on it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know whether that qualifies for a "non-trivial", but there is a calculator example: http://re-factor.blogspot.com/2010/08/calculator-with-gui.html

(github: https://github.com/mrjbq7/re-factor/blob/master/calc-ui/calc-ui.factor)